# CRON in node application with docker-compose not firing jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, docker-compose, schedule

I am using cron in my node-express application which is perfectly work if run application with 'node app.js' . Since from I dockertized my app, cron doesn't firing jobs. but if I just start app with node app.js it works well. I search every where but I get results for 'crontab' Or 'start schedule from dockerfile' only. I am new in docker thing. Is there anything I need to add for docker-compose so that it will work from node application ? following is my cron job function.

```
let myJobs = {}
let uniqueJobName = getUniqueId() // generating uniqe id for each job
myJobs[uniqueJobName] = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '* * * * * *',
  onTick: function () {
    // calling my function
    console.log('Invoked')
  },
  start: false
})
myJobs[uniqueJobName].start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find out the issue. Docker run default with UTC time zone. I have not provided the timezone in CRON job and I am testing with local timezone.
We can provide timezone in job like following,

```
timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Or

From docker we can add our local files (/etc/timezone and /etc/localtime) as volume in our docker-container.

```
volumes:
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

Hope it will help someone.